# validating name and value in array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$team = array("tom"=>"35",
"beck"=>"18",
"Gerald"=>"15");
```

I also am parsing data from a loop which gives me the following strings $name and $num

- The $name string returns a team members name from a database
- The $num string returns a team members number from a database

I would like to build a php if statement that will do the following:

1. Check if the $name and $num exists in the array $team
2. Check if the $num matches the assigned number for the name in the array

As an example, lets assume the following:

- $name = "tom";
- $num = "25";

I have this so far:

```
if (in_array($num, $team)) {
// do something
}
```

What's missing is for it to check the second condition mentioned above.

Following the above example, it should fail, since the $num value is "25", whereas it is "35" in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check the `$name` key with value of `$num` -

```
$team = array("tom"=>"35",
"beck"=>"18",
"Gerald"=>"15");

if(isset($team[$name]) && $team[$name] == $num) {
     // Your code
}
```

`in_array` will check for the `value`'s existence in the array without considering the `key`.